# How to display the total sum in textbox?

Tags: vb.net

I've just searched through vb.net examples on how to get the "SUM of a database", now I got this but how would I display this in textbox1 and textbox2?

But I don't know how to insert this to textbox.

```
 Try
        conn = New OleDbConnection(Get_Constring)
        conn.Open()
        cmd.Connection = conn
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
       sSQL=" Select userName,sum(quiz) as SumQuiz,sum(total) as Total From xxx where [username]='ad' And studentID='1111111'"
        cmd.CommandText = sSQL
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
```

Answer (score 1):

My VB is not that strong. You can try out `OleDbDataReader` for reading the data into variables. Then assign the value of the variable to `textbox1.Text` and `textbox2.Text`

```
Dim user As String
Dim sumQuiz As Integer
Dim total As Integer
Try
    conn = New OleDbConnection(Get_Constring)
    conn.Open()
    cmd.Connection = conn
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
   sSQL=" Select userName,sum(quiz) as SumQuiz,sum(total) as Total From xxx where [username]='ad' And studentID='1111111'"
    cmd.CommandText = sSQL
    OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    If dr.Read() Then
        set user = Convert.ToString(dr["userName"])
        set sumQuiz = Convert.ToInt32(dr["SumQuiz"])
        set total = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Total"])
    End If
```